# Why doesn't the object fall into the other object?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I want my small object to fall inside the shell of the larger sculpture. Why does it just hit the top plane of the object instead? Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the reason for this, is because your rigidbody is set to *Convex Hull*  which means it takes the outside of the mesh, and gives it collision box, and it just fills in all the holes.

If you want an object to fall inside a hole, all you need to do is change your rigidbody from *Convex Hull* to *Mesh*  as illustrated.

[image]